# MySQL query optimization for OR's with 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have something like this:

tables:

```
ct_lectures [id, l_id,name,position]

ct_teachers_lectures [id, t_id, l_id]

ct_teachers [id, name, surname, position]

ct_teachers_languages [id, t_id, lang_id]
```

First I list all lectures and then I try to find teachers that are connected with those lectures and speak specific language:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ct_teachers.* FROM ct_teachers_lectures, ct_teachers, ct_teachers_languages WHERE (

(ct_teachers_lectures.l_id = 27 AND ct_teachers.id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id AND ct_teachers_languages.t_id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id) OR 
(ct_teachers_lectures.l_id = 67 AND ct_teachers.id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id AND ct_teachers_languages.t_id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id) OR 
(ct_teachers_lectures.l_id = 133 AND ct_teachers.id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id AND ct_teachers_languages.t_id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id) OR 
(ct_teachers_lectures.l_id = 262 AND ct_teachers.id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id AND ct_teachers_languages.t_id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id)

ORDER BY ct_teachers.id DESC LIMIT 30
```

There can be even 15 lectures (above example is with 4) I want to seach, so there will 15 times that line:

```
(ct_teachers_lectures.l_id = **ID** AND ct_teachers.id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id AND ct_teachers_languages.t_id = ct_teachers_lectures.t_id) OR
```

Is there better way to get those teachers from database instead of making that big query? Or it's normal that those queries are that big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      ct_t.* 
   FROM 
      ct_teachers ct_t 
         INNER JOIN ct_teachers_lectures ct_tlect 
            ON ct_tlect.t_id = ct_t.id 
         INNER JOIN ct_teachers_languages 
            ON ct_tlang.t_id = ct_tlect.t_id 
   WHERE 
          ct_tlect.l_id = 27 
       OR ct_tlect.l_id = 67 
       OR ct_tlect.l_id = 133 
       OR ct_tlect.l_id = 262 
   ORDER BY 
      ct_t.id DESC 
   LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: Additionally, you could use where ct_tlect.l_id IN ( 27, 67, 133, 262 )

Answer (score 0):

Without having looked at the JOINs specifically, using multiple queries with `UNION ALL` instead of `OR` could be an option.

Comment: Thanks. So every tritment id has it's own SELECT and UNION between those SELECTs? I think it's better to use UNION cause I want to have unique teachers list.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But as you already noticed this may then return duplicates (which may or may not exist, depending on your data). But using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` defeats the purpose, since the results must then be sorted again by the database, which hurts performance. So better go with the query proposed above!